# Gallery in Android

Tags: android, gallery

I am using a gallery in my app. I am using the code given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341158/android-align-first-item-in-gallery-to-the-left). The problem is while clicking a item in gallery it moves to the left (as default gallery property is to move the item selected to the center).How to stop the item to scroll to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the Horizontal Scroll of the Gallery element.

```
gallery.scrollTo(yourOffset,0);
```